# How do I explode a column in mysql database laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table that has a column called year. The year column contains data such as 2022-2023. I want to separate 2022 from 2023 using `explode()`, but it is not working. It stops at the first row.

```
public function extractEndYear()
{
    $experience = Experience::all();

    foreach ($experience as $item) 
    {
        print  $item->year . "<br />";
        dd(explode("-", $item->year));
    }
}
```

Comment: well you are killing the script in the first iteration ...

Comment: @etranz in this case you can use `dump()` instead of `dd()`

Comment: @Pippo how that will help him to separate the data? `dump()` will dump the data for the each iteration.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, I assume that *etrenaz* is testing the loop for the moment...

Comment: @etranz I assume that you held this data before to pass it to the render. Can you describe what is a final data you trying to achieve?

Comment: @etranz Because when you print `inside the controller` sooner or later you will have a problem, and this is not a good practice to do that, ONLY if you DEBUG some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function extractEndYear() {
  $experience = Experience::all();

  foreach ($experience as $item) {
    print $item->year . "<br />";
    $years = explode("-", $item->year);
    print "Start Year: " . $years[0] . "<br />";
    print "End Year: " . $years[1] . "<br />";
  }
}
```

In this code, we remove the `dd(explode("-", $item->year))` line and instead assign the result of `explode()` to the `$years` variable. Then, we print the start year and end year separately using `$years[0]` and `$years[1]`, respectively.